# Can only define custom mongoose methods in options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to the mongoose docs, there are 3 ways to add custom methods to your documents:

1. Through schema options
2. Directly assigning a "methods" object to the schema
3. Using the Schema.method() helper

However, after many tries, I have only managed to get methods working using option 1.
I am curious as to why options 2 & 3 are not working for me. here is my code:

app.js

```
socket.on("message", async function (clusterData, callback) {
  console.log("socket event fired");
  const parentCluster = await Message.findById(clusterData.clusterId);
  coonsole.log(parentCluster); // exists as expected

  parentCluster.optionsMethod(); // log : "options method called" ✔
  parentCluster.objectMethod(); // error : parentCluster.objectMethod is not a function ❌
  parentCluster.helperMethod(); // error : parentCluster.helperMethod is not a function ❌
});
```

Message.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  mentions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  text: { type: String, trim: true },
  file: { type: String },
  dateString: { type: String, required: true },
  timestamp: { type: Number, required: true },
});

const messageClusterSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    sender: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    channel: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Channel",
      required: true,
    },
    group: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Group",
      required: true,
    },
    content: [messageSchema],
    clusterTimestamp: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    methods: {
      optionsMethod() {
        console.log("options method called");
      },
    },
  }
);
messageClusterSchema.virtual("lastMessage").get(function () {
  return this.content[this.content.length - 1];
});

messageClusterSchema.pre("validate", function () {
  console.log("pre validate ran");
  this.clusterTimestamp = this.content[this.content.length - 1].timestamp;
});


// assign directly to object
messageSchema.methods.objectMethod = function () {
  console.log("object method called");
};

// assign with helper
messageSchema.method("helperMethod", function () {
  console.log("helper method called");
});

console.log(messageSchema.methods); // {objectMethod: [Function (anonymous)], helperMethod: [Function (anonymous)]}
console.log(messageSchema.methodOptions); // { helperMethod: undefined }

const Message = mongoose.model("Message", messageClusterSchema);

export default Message;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that,
`objectMethod` and `helperMethod` is in `messageSchema` and In Message.js file, you are creating model of `messageClusterSchema` which you are importing and using in socket function. Both methods can only be called with a model-instance of `messageSchema`. And that's why `optionsMethod` is calling, but the other two are not. Basically you need to create model of `messageSchema` and export it to use it in other files.

In short, the error is:

```
const Message = mongoose.model("Message", messageClusterSchema);
```

The model is generated using `messageClusterSchema`, but the methods are assigned to `messageSchema`:

```
messageSchema.methods.objectMethod = function () {
  console.log("object method called");
};

// assign with helper
messageSchema.method("helperMethod", function () {
  console.log("helper method called");
});
```

They should be assigned to `messageClusterSchema`.